# How do I run this smart contract function using nethereum to return a result?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ethereum, geth

I followed a great article online to create a smart contract with CRUD operations.

This is the function I can't get working:

```
function getUserAtIndex(uint index)
    public
    constant
    returns(bytes32 userKey)
  {
    return userIndex[index];
  }
```

I've deployed the contract and can get the function using:

```
  var getUserAtIndex = contract.GetFunction("getUserAtIndex");
```

I want to know how I can use this to get the user details at that index by using that function?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```cs
var result = getUserAtIndex.CallAsync<byte[]>(123);
```